# operator -overloading in C++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I have a assignment that construct Operator overloading with bitwise.I try to construct ***operator<<*** to shift integer left,but when I declare function is:
***friend const int operator<<(const int& , int& );*** the complier notice error ***nomember operator requier a parameter with class or enum type.***. So I don't operator overloading with ***operator<<***. This is my code:

```
#pragma once//bitwise.h
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class bitwise
{   private: 
    int n;
public:
    bitwise(int n){
        this->n = n;
    }
    friend const int operator<<(const int& , int& );//complier notice error here.
};
const int operator<<(const int& n, int& x){
    int temp=n*pow(2, x);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's the rule. You can only overload operator with user-defined type.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are creating the operator, it is trying to redefine what it means to use shift-left with two integers, and not with your class.  You want something like this:

```
friend int operator<<(const bitwise& , int);
```

Comment: thanks, I  have just done. But I read in my document "operator<<" can declared as:    "friend T operator<<(const T& , T&);". Is this wrong?

Comment: @NguyenVanBinh: That's true as long as `T` is not a built-in type.

Comment: Ok, I understand. thank you so much.